# Fallback to auth_request if auth_basic_user_file fails in nginx

Tags: file, authentication, nginx, fallback, auth-request

How to first have nginx attempt to authenticate the incoming request using basic file authentication and only fallback to using auth_request if file auth fails? I'm trying to replicate the behavior of AuthBasicProvider in Apache where, for example, "AuthBasicProvider file ldap" could be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
satisfy any;
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /path/to/auth/file;
auth_request /auth-endpoint;
```